# jQuery CSS styling stays the same even if the link is not the current one

Tags: jquery, css

I found this jQuery code on a forum: http://jsfiddle.net/nZLpk/8/
However, if I change the code to this http://jsfiddle.net/c5LTj/ (modifying `$(this).css({'font-weight': 'bold', 'border-left': '5px solid #555554'});` the border will stay on the link even if that is not the selected one... Please help. Thanks!

Comment: You know jsFiddle has 4 different panels? HTML, CSS, JavaScript and Preview. It also defaults to an html5 doctype and you don't need the `head` nor the `body`.

Comment: Ya, I know.  The code is not originally mine though.  I got it like that, so I modified it like that...

Comment: Not only that, but the important parts of the code should be in the question itself. You have to imagine that if jsFiddle went down, people could still understand your question and help. Otherwise, it's not a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reset `border-left` on all elements with class `atag` the same way you are resetting their `font-weight`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.atags').click(function(){
        $('.atags').css({"font-weight":"300", 'border-left': '0'});
        $(this).css({'font-weight': 'bold', 'border-left': '5px solid #555554'});
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c5LTj/1/

If you just want to change the color, as you said the comment below:

```
$('.atags').css({"font-weight":"300", 'border-left-color': '#555554'});
$(this).css({'font-weight': 'bold', 'border-left-color': '#eee'});
```

You could also improve your code a lot if you remove `showonlyone` and the inline `href="javascript:showonlyone` instances, and do the work of `showonlyone` in the same place where you're changing the appearance of the links.

Comment: It does work, thanks. But, what would I do if I already have  a `border-left: 5px solid #eee;` on the links.  What I am trying to do is to make the current border-left #555554 and the others #eee.  But, when I click on one.  The #eee border on the other <a> disappear...

Comment: So use `border-left-color` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate that the people answering the question are answering the real question ("How do I fix this exact code so that my expected result appears?"), but I would take this opportunity to point out a different approach.

You should simply define a class with CSS that will encapsulate everything you need to happen, and then add that class with `addClass()` or remove it with `removeClass()`. A classic way of handling removing isn't even to track which element to remove it from, but to remove it from ALL before re-applying to only the necessary one (which I just noticed is more or less what the existing code is doing anyhow, except with styles instead of the class).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.atags').click(function(){
        $('.atags').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: Note that if you want to change some properties but not others (ie the color thing), you can add multiple classes and remove just some.

Comment: So I should just add `.selected {
 border-left: 5px solid #555554;
 color: #555554;
}` or whatever I want to my .css sheet? Thanks for your patience

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Sorry, it's just that I am a new to jQuery, so I just thought @bfavaretto's answer, even if it wasn't the best practice.  It was just easier for me.  Thank you for your help again though.

Comment: That's fine. :) You should accept the answer that you actually used! I can't help mentioning, however, that since you're new to jQuery (and possibly JavaScript in general), that you won't learn very quickly if you don't at least try this stuff out. Use the technique that's easiest for just moving forward now, but then when you have time, set up a jsFiddle or a quick page in your test environment and you'll see how easy this really is!

Comment: See my response, I believe I posted it before this discussion started.  In the Fiddle I do exactly this, as well as factor the JavaScript into events instead of using inline `href` or `onclick` embedded code.

Comment: @jMerliN Your answer appeared 7 minutes after mine, which is why the conversation had already started here. The code being referenced in this example and others doesn't have inline href or onclick embedded code, so I'm not sure what you mean by that part.

Answer (score 0):

You're not reseting the border,

```
 $('.atags').click(function(){
        $('.atags').css({"font-weight":"300", "border-left":0});
        $(this).css({'font-weight': 'bold', 'border-left': '5px solid #555554'});

})
```

should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to add `border-left` to the css you're applying to all `.atags` elements before applying a bold style.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.atags').click(function(){
        $('.atags').css({'font-weight': '300', 'border-left': '0px'});
        $(this).css({'font-weight': 'bold', 'border-left': '5px solid #555554'});
    });
});
```

I would suggest doing this with CSS classes instead of directly specifying the styles in your code, and not using JavaScript within an HTML attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/c5LTj/3/.